# Why it ignores my while condition when I input an void string ('nothing here')?

Tags: python, inputverifier

I have this code:

```py
sex = str(input('type sex:')).upper()

while sex not in 'MF':
    sex = str(input('try again: ')).upper()
print('Done!!!')
```

It works fine as a validation thing when I try to input almost anything, but when it's '', it just jumps over my while loop.
I've tried initializing the sex string in the beginning, but it didn't help :c

Comment: `'MF'` does contain an empty string - three of them, in fact.  Your test would also allow `'MF'` to be entered, as you aren't checking the substring length at all.  Try `sex not in ('M', 'F')` to allow only those two particular inputs.

Comment: @jasonharper beat me to it; I missed this at first due to battle fatigue.
Yes, the empty string is included in *any* string.

Comment: Thank you very much, helped a lot. I'm really new into programming, but liking it so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As jasonharper said, `'MF'` contains 3 empty strings. To fix it, you could change the code to:

```py
while sex not in ('M', 'F'):
    sex = str(input('try again: ')).upper()
print('Done!!!')
```

Or if you really want to use `'MF'`, you could have an additional check for an empty string in the while loop:

```py
while not sex and sex not in 'MF':
    sex = str(input('try again: ')).upper()
print('Done!!!')
```

Comment: I think `not sex` is more idiomatic for the first condition.

Comment: @kabanus Thanks for spotting that. I've gone and changed it now